# Can MatLab understand Java int datatype?

Tags: java, matlab, types

I have a java.util.HashMap object that I want to convert generally into a MatLab datatype, perhaps the new containers.Map type.

Ideally I could do:

```
it = javaHashMapObj.keySet.iterator;
while it.hasNext
    jkey = it.next;
    someMatlabObj(jkey) = javaHashMapObj.get(jkey);
end
```

Among other potential problems (please point out, resolve if they jump out at you!), there is the issue that if the Java HashMap is keyed with integers, `it.next` will nevertheless return MatLab double objects, which will then not work as keys into the HashMap with `javaHashMapObj.get`.

Can someone suggest a way to resolve this?  Extend the Java object to give me the MatLab int32 for the keys?

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB will convert a regularly entered number (which is a double) to a Java primitive int, but if you want an Integer Object, you have to explicitly box it yourself:

```
javaHashMapobj.get(java.lang.Integer(key));
```

See http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f6425.html for a table of how data types are converted from MATLAB to Java.

Comment: Thanks Mike, this is sort of the inverse of what I actually wanted to know, but still helpful.  

My problem is that when it.next should return a key that in Java is an Int, MatLab gets the key as a double.  Then when I try to use it.next to get the values from the Java object they don't work because the Java hash only has Int keys.

Of course, I could cast it.next to a MatLab int using int32(it.next) and then that value would work as a key into the Java hash.  But I am trying to have a way to handle this without a priori knowledge of the keys.

Comment: The link is dead. (Or rather, goes to the wrong page now.)